# Mysql fulltext search and table engine

Tags: mysql, sql, text

**"employees"** table has a 3 column

```
employee_name varchar(200),
employee_surname varchar(400),
address ntext
```

i wanna define full text search on table. Which one way is better ?

1- Create full text search index for every each column

2- Create one index for those 3 columns.

Comment: Depends on what you need to search, if you're never searching the address making it indexed is wasted work for MySQL, however if you regularly search all three columns at the same time index all three together, since that will reduce the amount of row level merging MySQL would need to handle.

Comment: Well i will search on this 3 columns. But 1 index for 3 columns or 3 diffrent index for every each column ? Which one is faster ?

Comment: One index on three columns is faster for searching three columns, but useless for searching individual columns, which is why I made it clear that what you're using it for is very important.

Comment: Thanks. What about integer columns ?

Comment: I mean i i have 3 columns integer and i will search on this 3 column. Which one is better 3 diffrent index for every each integer column or one index for theese 3 colmuns ?

Comment: Mergining indexs is expensive, but still less expensive than not being able to use an index at all. Doesn't matter what the type of the column is(within a certain measure of reason).